# We America.... and not We Americans -what is this special use?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, proper-nouns, appositives

I was reading articles on [the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2003/06/29/opinion/is-google-god.html) and found this.

> None of this means **we, America,** just have to do what the world wants, but we do have to take it seriously, and we do have to be good listeners.
>
> **We, America,** ''have to work even harder to build bridges,'' argues Mr. Wright, because info-tech, left to its own devices, will make it so much easier for small groups to build their own little island kingdoms.

Why is that? How do we call ourselves the nation itself (America) rather than its citizen (American)?

Comment: Because the action is done by the country, not the people. It's identical to saying "France declared war on Germany".

Answer (score 4):

This is just using America as an appositive; "We Americans", without commas, would also be acceptable here. The reason for using "America", the singular noun, is to give the connotation  that America must work as a group.